# Do we have API access to C4R(Collaboration for Revit) functionalities in Forge API/Revit API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

We recently have an enquiry to automate the C4R(Collaboration for Revit) process. Do we have API access to C4R functionalities in Forge API/Revit API?  We have searched for API access and we did not find any positive results.

Alternatively, if we upload the Revit model files via BIM 360 API then the Revit project file (.rvt) is getting disconnected/not available for the work-sharing environment. Is there any possible workaround to resolve this.

Comment: Sorry for the late. I'm looking into it. Please bear with me, it requests extra time to verify it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To activate C4R model via Revit API, please do the following steps at least :

1. Initiate a none-workshared cloud model through the API call to
   [Document.SaveAsCloudModel](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/c72daf7a-43da-a480-d093-e3d6a96d9a76.htm).
2. Convert it to a C4R model via the API
   [Document.EnableCloudWorksharing](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/4146e816-565e-85d8-ce94-93ec505a0924.htm)

Here is a working code snippet, and its' logic:

1. Create Architecture project with Revit template
2. Save it to local disk, then save it as the cloud model
3. Activate Revit Cloud Collaboration (C4R) via [Document.EnableCloudWorksharing](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/4146e816-565e-85d8-ce94-93ec505a0924.htm)
4. Open the C4R model in Revit desktop

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection;


    namespace adsk.c4r
    {
        [Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
        public class Command : IExternalCommand
        {
            public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
            {
                UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
                UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
                Application app = uiapp.Application;


                string template = app.DefaultProjectTemplate;
                string filename = @"C:\tmp\revit_api_c4r_test.rvt";
                string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename);

                Document newdoc = app.NewProjectDocument(template);
                newdoc.SaveAs(filename);


                try
                {
                    newdoc.SaveAsCloudModel("urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.OOOOOXXXXX", name);
                    var cloudPath = newdoc.GetCloudModelPath();
                    var newdocCanC4R = newdoc.CanEnableCloudWorksharing();

                    if(newdocCanC4R)
                    {
                        newdoc.EnableCloudWorksharing();
                    }

                    TaskDialog.Show("Revit", string.Format("{0} is a C4R model now", name));
                    newdoc.Close();

                    uiapp.OpenAndActivateDocument(cloudPath, new OpenOptions(), false);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    return Result.Cancelled;
                }

                return Result.Succeeded;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

**Note1.** Cloud Model for Revit entitlement is required for this approach. If you cannot save the cloud models, please check this page: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Using-Cloud-Worksharing-and-Cloud-Models-for-Revit.html

**Note2.** This approach has to use **Forge Data Management API** to obtain folder id while calling the Document.SaveAsCloudModel. The folder id also can be found in the BIM360 Docs URL while viewing Docs folder.For example, your folder URL is: https://docs.b360.autodesk.com/projects/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/folders/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.OOOOOXXXXX/detail, the folder id is `urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.OOOOOXXXXX`